# How to enforce associativity rules in a GLR parser?

Tags: parsing, glr

I'm writing a GLR for fun (again, because I understood a few things since my last try). The parser is working now and I am implementing disambiguation rules. I am handling precedence in a way that seems to work. Now I'm a bit at loss regarding associativity.

Say I have a grammar like this :

```
E <- E '+' E (rule 1)
E <- E '-' E (rule 2)
E <- '0'     (rule 3)
E <- '1'     (rule 4)
```

Where rules 1) and 2) have the same precedence and left associativity.

Without associativity handling, the string '1-1+0' will generate two parse trees:

```
   1                2
  / \              / \
 /   \            /   \
2     3          4     1
|  \                   | \
4   4                  4  3
```

Where numbers indicate the rule used for reduction. The correct parse tree is the first one and thus I would like to keep only this one.

I'm wondering how to efficiently detect associativity infringements algorithmically.

One approach I tried was to see that in the first tree, at the top node, rule 2 is LEFT of rule 3 in the list of children of rule 1, whereas in the second tree rule 1 is RIGHT of rule 4 and thus since rules 2 and 1 are LEFT associative I keep only the first tree.

This, however, did not get me very far in more complicated examples. A limitation of this solution is that I can only discard trees based on a comparison with another tree.

Do you think I can find a solution using a refined version of this approach? What is the standard way of doing?

Comment: non-associativity rules would also be nice...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is best expressed by integrating into the grammar rules, completely resolving the ambiguity:

```
E <- F
E <- E '+' F
E <- E '-' F
F <- '0'
F <- '1'
```

As you are set for (G)LR, it should be possible to equally well express left- and right-associativity. The increase in depth of parse trees, due to unit derivations, can be addressed by postprocessing them appropriately.

This will completely avoid inventing a new mechanism, and exploit the expressiveness of the BNF that is used anyway. I think it requires strong arguments to instead favor an ambiguous notation, plus a separate specification of how to resolve.

The XQuery language specification, during its definition process, evolved from using ambiguous EBNF with extra disambiguation rules (see [April 30, 2002 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-xquery-20020430/#prod-Expr)) to dropping the latter in favor of unambiguous rules incorporating precedence and associativity (see [August 16, 2002 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-xquery-20020816/#prod-Expr)). As an implementer, I very much appreciated that - it made my life easier.

Comment: The only argument in favor of ambiguity that I see is that it is easier for the person writing the grammar! And I must admit I rather like the argument. If it were at all possible to disambiguate automatically (say : all rules have left associativity by default, user can override this.) I would like this. Also, can you always integrate the precedence rules into the grammar?

Answer (score 0):

To do this algorithmically I would make two groups: SIMPLE which includes rule 3 and 4 and COMPLEX which includes rule 1 and 2. If the rightmost child of a (COMPLEX) (sub)root is COMPLEX then remove this tree because it is (partly) right-associative.